# Estilizar FileUpload

Tags: html, css

Como estilizar um elemento FileUpload? já vi alguns exemplos aonde fazem gambiarras para esconder o elemento e colocar uma imagem por baixo, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece outra forma de estilizar esse elemento.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomFileInputs/

Answer (score 0):

Estilizar uma tag input do tipo file requer um pouco de trabalho, os navegadores não mantem o mesmo padrão para esse elemento e isso dificulta manter algo bacana em nossa aplicação.

Abaixo, um exemplo de como fazer a estilização do campo input e outro link é de um componente jQuery, muito bacana e vale a pena usar para nao ter esse trabalho todo.

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle

Você tambem pode ver um exemplo no [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/aestheticartist/txnjfgwu/).